# Negative Pell equation $x^2-10y^2=-1$: problem with consecutive solutions

Tags: recurrence-relations, diophantine-equations, pell-type-equations

Consider the negative Pell equation:
$x^2-10y^2=-1$

Its integer positive fundamental solution is $(x_1, y_1)=(3,1)$. On the online solver (https://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM), we know that:

$x_{n+1}=19x_n+60y_n$

$y_{n+1}=6x_n+19y_n$

By applying those formulas, we obtain the following consecutive solutions to the Pell equation: $(117,37), (4443,1405), (168717,53353), (6406803,2026009)$.

Next solution should be: $(243289797, 76934989)$, but using these values, we get:

$243289797^2-10(76934989^2)=0$

Consequently also the next solution, produce the same result:

$9238605483^2-10(2921503573^2)=0$

Why the recurrence formula generated by the online solver (but also by a solver I'm programming: same results) give this error for bigger solution?

Comment: That can't possibly be right because $243289797^2$ is odd and $10(76934989^2)$ is even, so their difference can't be $0.$ Are you perhaps reaching the limit of your calculator's precision?

Comment: Yeah, I get $-1$ for both values using an arbitrary-precision calculator.

Comment: @thomas-andrews as you correctly pointed out, I switched onto working on 128-bit numbers, and the equation works.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews:  I think you should post an answer based on your comments; cf. [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=243289797%5E2%E2%88%9210%2876934989%5E2%29)

Comment: also: becomes separate recurrences, $$ x_{n+2} = 38 x_{n+1} - x_n, $$ $$ y_{n+2} = 38 y_{n+1} - y_n $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using limited-precision numbers, I'd guess.

Since $243289797^2$ is odd and $10(76934989^2)$ is even, their difference can't be $0$.

Computing with arbitrary precision, I get $-1$ for both values.

Comment: It would be useful for future readers. Using the R package Rmpfr, with precision 128   bits, I get the correct answer. Thank you.